# Erro "Signature (return type) of EventHandler..."

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-forms

Dando o erro:

**Signature (return type) of EventHandler "FoodSuppy.Tela.SolicitacaoCompra.BtnIncluir_Clicked" doesn't match the event type    FoodSuppy.**

Os botões do meu aplicativo começaram a dar essa mensagem depois que atualizei os pacotes NuGet. Gostaria de saber como resolver.

Segue código:

```
//Botão Incluir
        private async Task BtnIncluir_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Enviar ao banco
            Retorno retorno = await BuscarSolicitacaoCompras.BuscaInformacao("1", 0);

            await Navigation.PushAsync(new ItensCompra(Convert.ToString(retorno.ID_RET), "Incluir"));

            AtualizaDados(usuario);
        }
```

O código que está vinculado ao botão é esse:

```
//Buscar Solicitação de Compra
    class BuscarSolicitacaoCompras
    {
        private static Login1 usuarioConectado = new Login1();

        private static readonly string UrlBase = "http://sibrati.com.br/foodsupply/ie_solcompra.php?op={0}&idu={1}&ids={2}";

        public async static Task<Retorno> BuscaInformacao(string op, int ids)
        {
            usuarioConectado = Conectado.Pegar_ClienteConectado();

            string URL = string.Format(UrlBase, op, usuarioConectado.ID_USUARIO, ids);

            HttpClient http = new HttpClient();

            var response = await http.GetAsync(URL);
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var retorno = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Retorno>(content);

            return retorno;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Eventos de qualquer tipo não retornam valores, são "void". Ele está
>   reclamando dizendo que o `BtnIncluir_Clicked` não é compatível com
>   `EventHandler`, que tem a seguinte assinatura:
>
> ```
> public void Método(object sender, EventArgs e);
> ```
>
> Isso ocorre devido a existência do retorno `Task`. Tente colocar void
>   e veja se o compilador aceita.

Com essa resposta de um parceiro simplesmente troquei o `Task` pelo `void`:

```
private async void BtnIncluir_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ...
}
```